# Query class column of a specific user

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to query the column name of the class Survey from my models from a specific user_id. But i'm getting error when trying to do it.
This is how I'm doing:

```
>>> q = Survey.objects.filter(user=1)
>>> q.name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'
```

This is my model:

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    description = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user_survey_set")

    def __unicode__ (self):
        return (self.name)

    def questions(self):
        if self.pk:
            return Question.objects.filter(survey=self.pk)
        else:
            return None

    def user_data(self):
        p = self.user
        return p.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`QuerySet.filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#filter) returns `QuerySet` objects, not specific Model instance. To get specific model instance, use [`QuerySet.get`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#get) method:

```
>>> survey = Survey.objects.get(user=1)
>>> survey.name
```